# Restrict user to add only one chip in md-contact chip (Angular Material)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-autocomplete contact chip like this:

```
<div class="chipsdemoContactChips" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
  <md-content class="autocomplete" layout="column">
    <md-contact-chips placeholder="Type the email-addresses here"
      secondary-placeholder="Type email addresses here"
      ng-model="asyncContacts"
      filter-selected="filterSelected"
      md-highlight-flags="i"
      md-require-match="true"
      md-contact-email="email"
      md-contact-image="image"
      md-contact-name="name"
      md-contacts="delayedQuerySearch($query)">                                                              
    </md-contact-chips>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

The list is getting rendered properly and I am able to select as many contacts as possible. But I want the user to be able to add, maximum of "1" contact.

Comment: there is one pull request about to bring some md-chips features into md-contact-chips, but it is still not yet merged at the moment... https://github.com/angular/material/pull/6961. I guess you need to handle it on your own for now. or use md-chips instead.

Comment: As of now, I am making use of Jquery and it is working fine.